# C# Marshal.GetActiveObject() alternative for Outlook Automation on .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop, .net-5

I'm going to start a new project for Outlook interaction from external application (mail subject manipulation, clearing subject from Re: Fw: etc.. add subject tags, research subject tags in external DB etc..).
I'm used to call `Marshall.GetActiveObject()` method to take control of already running `Outlook Application`.

With the release of **.NET 5.0** I discovered that `Marshall.GetActiveObject()` method is no more available.

Is there an alternative way to do that?
I want to use **.NET 5.0** instead of **.NET Framework** in order to avoid any further problem with .NET Framework deprecations.

Thanks in advance, brgds.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is a singleton - there is always only one instance of outlook.exe running. There is absolutely no reason to use `Marshall.GetActiveObject()` - always create a new instance of the `Outlook.Application` object using the `new` operator.

Comment: I just wonder why this article on how to [Obtain and Log On to an Instance of Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/obtain-and-log-on-to-an-instance-of-outlook) by Microsoft MVP suggests the opposite.

Comment: That I don't know :-)

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application` is an interface, how can you `new` one

Comment: It is a creatable COM object  - .Net knows to instantiate it. The interface definition in the interop has CoClass attribute set.

Comment: @PeterWolf - the sample code you linked to uses Marshal.GetActiveObject - so it won't compile with NET5.0

Answer (score 0):

If it helps any, I am in the same boat - trying to port Outlook Interop code to NET 5 but without using `GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;` to get a reference to the running Outlook app. My NET Framework 4.8 code worked fine for a couple of years, so of course it is (was) possible to use GetActiveObject for the job.

But with NET 5, I am struggling to find a way to reference the Office apps. I show code below that works with Outlook (even though it should not, I think).

```
NET 4.8 (works)
var o = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;

NET 5.0 (works)
var o = Marshal.BindToMoniker("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
```

I don't know why BindToMoniker works - I thought it took a pathname as an argument. Anyhow, it works for me on Windows11 NET 5.0 with project TargetFramework and Interop.Outlook reference shown below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook">
```

I am still stuck on how to get references to running Office apps for Excel, Access, Word, etc.

UPDATE
Charlieface provided a link for me to the solution, which was to create my own Marshal2.GetActiveObject interface as shown in this post:

[How to connect an open excel application in net.core 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140188/how-to-connect-an-open-excel-application-in-net-core-3-1/70398580#70398580)