# Late Binding Interop libraries for usage on multiple systems with c#

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop, com-interop, office-automation

I am trying to write an application that can load the correct Interop office library and retrieve information about the application.
I have been trying to do this with word.

```
Type wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
dynamic word = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);

Console.WriteLine(word.Application.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName);
```

I have a word document open but I cannot access the window. It throws an error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1098): Dieser Befehl ist nicht
> verfügbar, weil kein Dokument geöffnet ist.

Which is translated to `no Document is availabe`.

However if I do not use late binding

```
var word = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)Marshal2.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
Console.WriteLine(word.Application.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName);
```

I can read the document file...

If I cannot use late binding I have to compile the interop and ship it with the application. My goal would be that it uses the interop of the programs that are installed, if they are installed.

How can I connect to the correct instance and read informations about the active window?

Comment: You don't have to ship interop. By default interop types will be embedded in your application (see "Embed Interop Types" in project properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/embed-types-visual-studio). That being said, the two pieces of code are not equivalent. The first one always creates a new instance of Word. The second one, we don't know. What's Marshal2? Replacing with Marshal creates another (expected) error 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE).

Comment: @SimonMourier Could you show me an example of how to access the active window with late binding. So far I can only see how I can create and Instance. I do not now how to connect to the running instance.

Comment: @SimonMourier marshal2 is a solution to make interop work with latest .net. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140188/how-to-connect-an-open-excel-application-in-net-core-3-1

Comment: Using late binding or early binding won't change anything to the problem. You just need to call the proper Word APIs. GetActiveObject gets you a currently running word instance if any. Just start with `dynamic word = Marshal2.GetActiveObject(...)`

Comment: Apples and oranges by the way.  In the first example you are spawning a new instance of the Word application (without any documents I might add), and the second is using IROT for an existing Word app that no doubt has a document and therefore active.

Comment: @SimonMourier your comment helped me understand where I was wrong and solved it for me. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apples and oranges by the way.  In the first example you are spawning a new instance of the Word application (without any documents I might add), and the second is using IROT for an existing Word app that no doubt has a document and therefore active.

---

In your first scenario, you merely spawned a new instance of a Word **but did not create a document**.  Like most *Office* applications, *Word* starts with **no** documents by default.

Change:

```
Type wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
dynamic word = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);

Console.WriteLine(word.Application.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName);
```

...to:

```
var wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);
dynamic doc = app.Documents.Add(); // <---- the important bit

Console.WriteLine(doc.FullName);
```

### See also

- *[Dynamic and COM Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-dynamic-net-understanding-the-dynamic-keyword-in-csharp-4#dynamic-and-com-interop)*
- *[How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-file-using-visual-c)*

Comment: This will only add another document but it will not access the currently opened dokument. I would like to read the FullName of the Document I have already opened manually with word. Is that possible?

Comment: @Silve2611 incorrect.  Refer to the links provided.